# How to find two closest (nearest) values within a vector in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector e.g. `A=[2.29 2.56 2.67 2.44 2.52 1.23]`

I am interested to find two closest (almost equal) values with in this vector.

Comment: For clarification, are you interested in the two closest adjacent values or the two closest regardless of position?

Comment: @RTL: any two closest value, irrespective of position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One-Liner Solution**

```
res = A(repmat(find(abs(diff(A))==min(abs(diff(A)))),2,1)+[0;1]);
```

**More descriptive solution**

```
%finds the index with the minimal difference in A
minDiffInd = find(abs(diff(A))==min(abs(diff(A))));
%extract this index, and it's neighbor index from A
val1 = A(minDiffInd);
val2 = A(minDiffInd+1);
```

Result:

```
val1 = 2.4400
val2 = 2.5200
```

Comment: your solution is perfect. Can it be extended to find closest element in any number of (two or more) equal sized vectors? i.e. out of a group of equal sized vectors, how to identify two closest elements in any two vectors, not within a vector as was done in above solution given by you.

Comment: Posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773140/how-to-find-closest-nearest-value-within-a-vector-to-another-vector-in-matlab it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pdist().

as in `pdist(A,A)`

Comment: Please add that this requires the `stats` toolbox.

Comment: pdist may also work, but seems to be costly in terms of time.